# 6 x TEC1-12706 in series cannot reach desired amperage, why?

Tags: series, peltier

]I have 6 EC1-12706 in series connected to a variable DC Power Supply (rated with maximum 30V and 10A). I set the power supply to 30V and 1.50A.

My problem is that the DC Power Supply when the output is enabled keeps the voltage to 30V but the ampere goes down to 1.29A.

Why does the power supply cannot provide the 1.5A desired?

My calculus is that in series the 30V should be divided by 6 (5V each TEC) and the amp distributed among the 6 equally.

Schematic:

[image]

Photo:

[image]

EC1-12706 DataSheet:
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/634368/HB/TEC1-12706/1

DC Power Supply:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07Y5XVTQL/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y5XVTQL)

Testing data:
I tested with a single EC1-12706 unit. I set the variable DC Power Supply to 12V and 5A, the power supply says (and the multimeter) says: 12V, 2.4A (cannot reach 5A, hence it seems that the 1.98ohms of the spec sheet is wrong?

Inside:
[image]

Comment: `I set the power supply to 30V and 1.50A.` ... what does that mean? ... what parameter are you actually setting?

Comment: The Ampere setting is a Limiter function... it does not make sense to use it here. How many Watt the supply has? at 30V at any case with 6 in a row the resistance is so low that more than 2A "want" to flow

Answer (score 2):

How much voltage drop is there in the wiring?

What deltaT do you have? The required voltage changes with the temperature difference.

Don't forget to take account the resistance of the meter (and it's leads). Even the ammeter will have resistance that will reduce the current, the current when you connect the TEC directly will be somewhat more.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for guiding me. I am very beginner to I will do my best. After 5 minutes, with the heatsink in place on the hot side, I am probing 23C and 31C (74F and 84F). Ambient temperature is 26.5C

Comment: After 10 minutes, the temperature is 14C and 28C. The module resistance from the spec sheet is 1.98 Omhs

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins - don't forget that the hotside temperature of the TEC will be a bit higher than that of the heat sink. The hot side only being 3C above ambient seems low since there are ~40W+ being dissipated.

Comment: _"My calculus is that in series the 30V should be divided by 6 (5V each TEC)"_ - can you measure the actual TEC voltages? Please show us a photo of your setup. _"Why does **the power supply cannot provide the 1.5A desired**?"_ - if the power supply continues to put out 30V under load then it _can_ deliver more current, but the load's resistance is limiting the current.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I added in the question a schema and a picture. When I connect the power supply to a single TEC I can set to 12V and only 2.4A even if I set the power supply to 12V and 6A which is what the spec sheet says could handle.

Comment: Isn't V=IR, hence 12V=1.98omh*xA, thus x could be 6A?

Comment: Yes, but only if the TEC really is 1.98 Ohms. According to your measurements one(?) of them is 12/2.4 = 5 Ohms. Where did you get your TECs from? What currents do the others draw at 12V?

Comment: I got the TEC on Amazon here: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01IT8SAZG
1.98 according to the spec sheet. They are all behaving the same way individually. I cannot get more than 2.4A when directly connected to the power supply when set for 12V and 5A. I used my multimeter and the amp at 12V/5A is 2.4A as well (thus the power supply values when running are the real ones)

Comment: I contacted the seller and they told me they sent me the wrong item... which I have a hard time to believe since it is written on the item "12706". I think they were just fake unit... :\ thanks for all the help, I've learned a lot in the process.

Comment: https://customthermoelectric.com/tech-info/te-encyclopedia/what-tec-do-i-have.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott Here is the inside. I could 14 which is not a 127 couples... https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJHsI.jpg

Comment: This *commentary* is not without its use here, but it's not actually an *answer*...

Comment: You are right @ChrisStratton, I'm trying to give the information I am discovering.

I've been reading the manual (https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1NdhNAQfKS.pdf) of the power supply and it says to set to 3V and to short-circuit while changing the amp to set the amp, which I did to 10A...

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that the DC Power Supply when the output is enabled
> keeps the voltage to 30V but the ampere goes down to 1.29A.
>
> Why does the power supply cannot provide the 1.5A desired?

Your power supply is working properly. It can supply *up to* 1.5A when the current limit is set to this value. If the load draws less than 1.5A the power supply will not force it to draw more.

Your problem is that your TEC modules have higher than expected resistance, and so are drawing less current than expected. This suggests that they are 'fakes' ie. lower spec devices with fake markings.

The site [What TEC do I have?](https://customthermoelectric.com/tech-info/te-encyclopedia/what-tec-do-i-have.html) shows how to measure the size of one semiconductor pellet in the TEC to determine its likely current rating.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple:

When its cold, you adjust the current to be 1,5A. (Ri is 6 × 1,98 Ω.)

When its hot resistance changes to 6 × 2,3 Ω.

1,5 / 2,3 × 1,98 = 1,291 A.

Comment: So you mean that I could raise the AMP by adding resistance in the circuit?

What do you mean "when it's hot" or "when it's cold" ?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins You know how a ThermoelectricCooler works? You have read the datasheet you linked to? And no, you can not raise AMP by adding resistance...

Comment: I know the basics of thermoelectric cooler works (as mentioned I am new in the field). I am learning by doing this exercise in which I have this question. I have read the datasheet but it is not very clear. I thought I could by modifying the voltage and amperage the temperature. Nothing talks about "when cold" or "when hot" in any tutorial or datasheet I have read. Sorry.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. When the device gets cold, the resistance is 1.98 but when it gets warm (delta T in the datasheet diagram) it makes the resistance increase. The more it gets warm, the more there is resistance. What is do not understand is still why if I use 1 unit at 12v and 5 amp that I still get 1.3 amp and not the total 5. The device is cold and 1 unit. The resistance should be 1.98, So 12/1.98 = about 6 amp, right?

Comment: Well you have 30V and 6*2,3 Ohm, because you choose series connection. this is 13,8 Ohm and 30 V / 13,8 Ohm is 2,173 A. It will never consume 5. If you connect 2 times 3 modules in series connection parallel, you can half the resistance and double the current. So with 2 times 3 in a row you get ~4,2A

Comment: And when connected, just rise the current limit. In the first case current should not exceed ~2,17A, and if you try my suggestion you should see the 4,2A. If its a short circut safe labbench supply try this, do not connect anything: adjust voltage. Set current knob to lowest setting! short circuit output, adjust current limit. Then connect your device. You will see that the power supply will limit with the set current now and not exceed the set voltage

Comment: I suddently understand! I will give it a try once I am done working. Thank you so much @schedan. I understand way better the whole idea and also how to read the 25C|50C on the datasheet with the different resistance.

Comment: The only mystery in my mind is when I use a single unit and set the power supply to 12v and 5amp. Even when the hot side reaches the hot module resistance of 2.30 Ohms, the amp should be able to reach 5.2A but it can barely get 1.3A.

Comment: This sounds strange... you're really sure the Power supply is not in current limiting mode when you try?

Comment: can you just let it run until operational temperature is reached, then measure resistance from the cables which run from the power supply to the device (unplug!) and if possible measure again as near to the device than possible - be quick, so temperature is not so different. Do you measure the expected values?

Comment: I set the power supply to 30V and 10A. Set the 6 TEC in parallel (3 each side in series) hence 30V, 5A each side. When running. for 1 sec (cold) I was able to see in the power supply 30V and 5.1A. I suspect more and more an issue with the TEC device. I contacted the seller he wrote to me: "We are so sorry that we have sent you the wrong item. As you know, nobody is perfect. There may be some mistake when we sell thousands of products each month. We do hope you could forgive us." Not sure I buy it since the device is marked with TEC1-12706 thus looks like a fake maybe... :\ I

Comment: I did the resistance test. Set the power supply to 10V and 5 A. Turn it on with the TEC connected for 5 seconds and disconnected. The data on the power supply was 10V and about 2A (and going down). When psu off, the resistance of the TEC was 1.2 omhs and moving down rapidly.

Comment: At least the device on your table seems not to behave like the data-sheet said... so despite from the wrong resistance and current values, do you see the cooling effect to work?

Comment: Just another thought: when you test it below 25°C in your room, you might see resistance to be lower then in the data sheet. And as the Current is going down that fast... I never considered it, as you use a huge heatsink, but are you sure the device and the heatsink are properly connected? Did you use thermal grease or a thermal silicon pad?

Comment: It cools down and I am using thermal pads on to connect to the heatsink which has 2 140mm fans. The fans help greatly to keep the aluminum heatsink lukewarm (I can touch with my fingers without problem). If I keep the running for 10 minutes, I can see some condensations on the cold plate. Thus, it "works" but not as theoretically was expecting.

Comment: And all 6 modules behave similar?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I am waiting a new set of TEC from a different seller. I will post once I can perform further tests